# the kernel module .ko files are sent as base64 encoded in thunderbird

Tags: linux, email, thunderbird, encoding

I am participating in the Eudyptula Challenge . where they need the attachments to be sent as text/plain . I tried it through various means and had a number of problems

-> gmail web ui - no facility to do that . only body can be set as plain text

-> used mailsend (https://github.com/muquit/mailsend) - I am unable to send the whole message body , but only line by line ... and it seems like it has a bug when sending three attachments . some are skipped .

-> evolution - still the attachments are base64 encoded
then finally I came to Thunderbird which many people say as successful sending patches.

Yes I tried using different links http://www.stabellini.net/thunderbird-configuration.txt , http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/email-clients.txt and configured thunderbird and now I will say what I achieved and what I need to achieve

I am sending
1) message body
2) three attachments

1. Makefile
2. logfile
3. task1.ko - a kernel module

what I need to achieve ?
send all the above as text/plain without base64 encoding

what I achieved ?
I got to send the

message body as

> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

logfile(attachment) as

> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8;
>    name="syslog"
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
>   Content-Disposition: attachment;
>    filename="syslog"

Makefile (attachment)

> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8;
>    name="Makefile"
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
>   Content-Disposition: attachment;
>    filename="Makefile"

task1.ko (attachment) as

> Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
>    name="task1.ko"
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
>   Content-Disposition: attachment;
>    filename="task1.ko"

the problem is the last one ... still task1.ko is being base64 encoded ..
if I send this mail in this form, the response mail says

> You sent me base64 attachments, which I can not understand at all :(
>   Please go read the introductory email again about why this is a bad
>   thing.  It is also a very normal thing to have happen if you are using
>   gmail, the web interface almost always does this.  Please see the kernel
>   file:
>           http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/email-clients.txt
>   for some hints on how to properly configure your email client on how to
>   be able to send attachments in a format that can be used by the kernel
>   community.

Someone please help me from this. I did the task 2 days ago and this mail sending is delayed because of this problem .. Please help ..

Note : I also have another doubt . the question says "
Also be sure to send the kernel module you wrote, along with
the Makefile you created to build the module." . Actually the problem is with sending the ko file which is a binary file . so have I misinterpreted the question and am I to send the .c file instead of the .ko file ?.. is it possible to send the binary file as UTF-8 text/plain still ?

Comment: Yes you should send source code and no you shouldn't attach binary pretending it's text/plain because lying about this doesn't help with anything.

Answer (score 0):

Base64-encoded is not a problem when sending binary files; it's the standard method these days. However, Eudyptula doesn't want the compiled module in the first place – it is useless for contest purposes. You must send the *source code* instead; that is, all the `.c` and `.h` files.